# How can I pull data from an API into a Discord Embed Message?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to pull data from an API using GET to display that information in a nice Discord Embed message that updated frequently. How can I use the information it gives me and display it in a discord embed?

Also, how can I make it so that an ID is instead shown as a Name instead of the ID itself?

The APIs I want to use are all here in this repo https://github.com/ToontownRewritten/api-doc

Comment: This depends on your API and isn’t standard. Depending on the type of response body you’ll get with your GET request, you’ll need to parse the body by using json or other text tools to grab the data you’d like. This post needs more information. There is a guide to actually send the embed here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview and more information about discord.js here: https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or JavaScript [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) function

Here is an example **(this is a very simplified example and probably will need big adjustments to work properly with your API, as an API requires authentication and no headers were mentioned on this fetch request)**:

```
fetch('url')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('hi')
    .setDescription(data)
    message.channel.send(embed)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Do something for an error here
  })
```

You change this to your needs, but just to give you a general idea.